# How do you explain agile process tool (like Scrum or Kanban) to a (traditional) project manager?

Tags: agile, scrum, management, kanban

I am sure many people involved in the software development projects came up with this question, but I could not actually come up with satisfying answer.

- How to explain to a manager used to having a huge gantt-chart, resource allocation, critical-paths (etc) benefits of using agile process tool such as Scrum or Kanban?

A typical problem is explaining why testing sometimes takes longer than the actually coding...

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: You can't. Just as "You can't teach old dog new tricks."

Comment: Possibly related?  [Are project managers useful in Scrum?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/40465/64132)

Comment: You start by asking him if he likes the constant updating of the gantt-charts due to hare-brained requests from the customer that get retracted or changed a few weeks later.

Comment: @DanPichelman Project managers, top-level managers are always there, no matter whether you are agile team for years or you just started using some agile framework...

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable in an objective manner, what agile development is, is objective, but there are very many ways of explaining the same thing, or very many answers none of which is correct or incorrect.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to check out and read [ProjectManagement.SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com).  While this question may not be appropriate there, there is a stronger focus on the specifics of project management and project managers (there is overlap between P.SE and PM.SE in this area) and they might have some questions there that specifically address your issues.

Comment: I am actually asking for **opinions**. I am fully aware that concise answer is not possible here!

Comment: @DejanLekic - Opinions are not what this Q&A site is designed for.  I think this question could work if you explained where you are having trouble communicating the process, and what push back you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right forum for this question, but since similar questions are already [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40465/are-project-managers-useful-in-scrum), my advice (out of experience) is:

Don't bother explaining. Rather, **show** him.

In particular, if you want to introduce agile or scrum processes, you'll have to do two jobs: on one side, report him the data he wants (Gantt charts, estimates). On the other, let your team work Scrum without interference. When things go well (they will if your team is with you) you can turn over and say "by the way, this time I managed things this way" and introduce him to agile.

A "traditional" PM is not opposed to process: however, they have probably been around long enough to survive most PM fads and would rather see results than babble.

Comment: Yeah, some people think my question is related to the "Are project managers useful in Scrum" thread. It is not. I have upvoted your answer, but some guys keep downvoting, I have no idea why to be honest...

Comment: It's a community, so majority vote rules. Thanks anyways :)