# Do we need project managers in the agile organisation when doing software development or are the project governance replaced by product governance?

Tags: agile, project-management, product-owner

Q: Do we need project managers in the agile organisation when doing software development or are the project governance replaced by product governance?

There are several questions asked and answered here about the role of project managers in Scrum. These questions come to some help but what I'm asking here is that the organisation I am working with has replaced project managers with product managers AND product owners. They prescribe to [Modern Agile](http://modernagile.org/). They do not prescribe to SCRUM.

My question is a bit wider encompassing agile SW development using any of XP, FDD, SCRUM, Kanban, Lean SW development, SAFe.

I have worked in an organisation on an agile transformation for quite a while and part of the transformation is replacing project governance and a maintenance organisation with a product governance and organisation. The SW dev organisation is built up by 30 product teams that manages the life cycle of 1 to 5 products, cross functional teams doing DevOps. Products being SW services w/wo UI addressing various needs of the organisation’s IT services needs across processes delivering end services to customers.

I often come across several turf wars when an organisation embarks on its agile (transformation) journey. One of these are the necessity or not of project managers in the agile SW organisation.

Project managers feels threatened by agile, maybe they have not been reskilling – keeping tabs i.e. they are not sure about the why and the how of agile. Or the agile operating model proposed seem to indicate new roles that somewhat looks like a project manager but is not – according to “agile people”.

In this organisation project managers are replaced by **product managers** accountable in the business for quality and delivery of services (budget, objectives, strategies, KPIs etc. These product managers are supported by **product owners** doing daily operative stuff to make sure the proper features are developed, and highest impact bugs are rectified.

***So are project managers needed in this kind of agile setup for SW continuous delivery – yes or no?***

If project managers are needed – why? 
What are the pros and cons of project managers?

If there are to be both project governance and product governance – what is the split in accountability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are project managers useful in Scrum?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40465/are-project-managers-useful-in-scrum)

Answer (score -1):

In theory no. In practice?

So yeah in theory your self managing agile teams don't need project managers. Stake holders throw items into the backlog and they get done.

In practice things can go bad.

A project manager is incentivised (paid bonuses) to complete projects to the satisfaction of the customer.

Developers don't get bonuses, they get told off if things go wrong and they get pay rises by learning cool new techs and leaving to work for someone else.

There is a basic problem here which can't be solved by methodology. You wan't people to care about 'best practice' and making sure things don't break, but not to the exclusion of obeying orders which might not be in their best interest.

The general solution is to have two sets of people, both arguing their case and hope that a happy medium is reached. Its not about the tasks they do, its about the perspective they bring.